# How can I build <feature_name : feature_weight> dict in Tensorflow v2.4

Tags: tensorflow, feature-engineering

I am new in tensorflow. I use tf.feature_column to finish feature_engineering task, including crossed_column operation. After a simple LR model, **I can get the feature_weight for every feature, but how do I know the feature's name? For example:**

```
my_features = []
weight = IndicatorColumn(categorical_column=VocabularyListCategoricalColumn(key='weight', vocabulary_list=(2, 3, 0, 1), dtype=tf.int64, default_value=-1, num_oov_buckets=0))
my_features.append(weight) 

vol = IndicatorColumn(categorical_column=VocabularyListCategoricalColumn(key='vol', vocabulary_list=(3, 4, 1, 2), dtype=tf.int64, default_value=-1, num_oov_buckets=0))
my_features.append(vol)

weight_X_vol = tf.feature_column.crossed_column( [feature_weight, feature_vol], has_bucket_size = 50) 
my_features.append(weight_X_vol)
```

in feature_weight, it's one_hot feature size is 4(weight0, 1, 2, 3)

in feature_vol, it's one_hot feature size is 4(vol0, 1, 2, 3)

in feature_weight_X_vol, it's one_hot feature size is 16(weight0_vol0, weight0_vol1, ...., weight3_vol3)

so my features_size is 4 + 4 + 16 = 24

After fit a simple LR model, I can get the 24 feature_weight by model.layers[1].get_weights(), **but how can I build a dict to map feature_name(key) to the feature_weight(value)? For example:**

```
my model is :
my_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(my_features),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activatio="sigmoid")
    ])
feature_weight = my_model.layers[0].get_weights()

my weight is :
faeture_weight = [0.1, 0.2, 0.1, ..., 0.8, 0.4. 0.3] //lengh is 24

my feature_name is :
feature_name = [weight0, weight1, weight2, ..., vol0, vol1, ..., weight0_vol0, weight3_vol3] // lengh is 24
```

**How can I map the key to the value? I just want to know every feature's weight for debuging.**

Comment: I guess `feature_name` is a `list` of `str`?  try `dict(zip(feature_name, feature_weight))`

Comment: thanks for your comments, I think my representation is not clear. 
I just only know the feature_weight by layer.get_weights() function, it's show me a weight numpy array, but I don't know whether feature_weight[i] is feature_name[i]'s weight, maybe feature_weight[0] is feature_name[1]'s weight. In other words, I don't know how tf.feature_column generate the one-hot arrays, especially in columned_features.